# Laravel - How to add where clause in LaravelChart model

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this code:

```
   $chart_settings = [
        'chart_title'        => 'Users By Months',
        'chart_type'         => 'line',
        'report_type'        => 'group_by_date',
        'model'              => 'App\\User',
        'group_by_field'     => 'last_login_at',
        'group_by_period'    => 'month',
        'aggregate_function' => 'count',
        'filter_field'       => 'last_login_at',
        'column_class'       => 'col-md-12',
        'entries_number'     => '5',
    ];
    $chart = new LaravelChart($chart_settings);
```

How do I add this where clause to the code above  ( 'model'              => 'App\User',)

```
where('hr_status', 0)->where('company_id', $userCompany)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the LaravelChart class code

Answer (score 1):

You can use **where_raw** to specify custom where condition

```
$chart_settings = [
    'chart_title'        => 'Users By Months',
    'chart_type'         => 'line',
    'report_type'        => 'group_by_date',
    'model'              => 'App\\User',
    'group_by_field'     => 'last_login_at',
    'group_by_period'    => 'month',
    'aggregate_function' => 'count',
    'filter_field'       => 'last_login_at',
    'column_class'       => 'col-md-12',
    'entries_number'     => '5',
    'where_raw'          => 'hr_status = 0 AND company_id ='.$userCompany
];
$chart = new LaravelChart($chart_settings);
```